# Angular Dynamic Component Change Detection Not Working

Tags: angular, leaflet

I am having an issue getting my dynamic Angular components to trigger change detection.

I was trying to following https://juristr.com/blog/2017/11/dynamic-angular-components-for-rendering-html/ this tutorial. I was successful in getting dynamic components to show up (yes I am also using leaflet). However when I want to update a component (popup) and i use the following lines of code (below) this "data" field does get updated with new values but the component never updates the values on the view. Any help with this would be appreciated.

```
updateIcon(markerLayer, color, i, sign?) {
    console.log('icon updates');
    const newNbOffset = this.elccMapLogicService.getPopupOffset(i, this.currentPopupOffset);
    const newIcon = L.icon({
        iconSize: [this.currentMarkerSize, this.currentMarkerSize],
        iconAnchor: this.currentIconOffset,
        iconUrl: 'assets/map_features/markers/sign-' + color + '.png',
        popupAnchor: [-newNbOffset[0], newNbOffset[1]]
    });
    markerLayer.setIcon(newIcon);
    if (sign) {
        this.northBoundMarkerComponents.forEach(component => {
            if (sign.plazaId === component.id) {

                component.componentInstance.data = sign;

                component.componentInstance.instance.cd.detectChanges();
            }
        });
    }
    markerLayer.getPopup().update();
}
```

Comment: Hi James, could you produce a [mcve] in something like StackBlitz?